# Store settings in localstorage per computer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created google chrome extensions which store settings in the local storage.  I have two computers with one google account and if I change this setting in one computer it will automatically update this setting in another computer.

Looks like google-chrome sync local storage between all computers with the same account.  How can I store extension's settings per computer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use chrome.storage.local() vs chrome.storage.sync() for this:

http://www.developer.com/lang/synchronized-storage-between-multiple-computers-with-chrome-sync.html

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome does not sync `localStorage` values between computers. You can use it to store values on each individual computer.